# Defining Wavefrom as an expression in LTSpice

Tags: ltspice

Is there a way to define a variable as a function of other nodes in LTSpice so that I can later plot it?

For example V(OUT) = (V+) - (V-)

And then I can plot V(OUT) without having to do the math equation each time in LTSpice? This is useful as I want to keep some measurements for V(OUT) but plan to change that expression.

Answer (score 0):

Found a workaround by creating dependent voltage source vb and defining it in terms of my expressions.

Comment: That's an easy-enough route. There are a number of others available, too. But good to hear you've got it worked.

Comment: If you make a function `f(x, y) {x - y}` (bogus example), and then input that in a behavioural source as `V = f( V(a), V(b) )`, you get what you wanted, but it's just the longer way of what seems you have already done. If it's simple math, it might be better to use `G` or `E` sources, over behavioural sources.